# sqlite fundamentals

Tags: sqlite

How to build sqlite3 library to use with bode blocks mingw compiler? Already I downloaded `sqlite amalgamation` it contains four files `shell.c, sqlite3.c, sqlite3.h, sqlite3ext.h` I want to create `sqlite3.a` library.

(I'm using win xp sp3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [recommended](http://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html) way to use SQLite is to compile it statically into your program, i.e., just add the `sqlite3.c` file to your other source files.

Comment: so how can I statically link sqlite engine to my applicatrion

Comment: no its clear. the compiler created a `sqlite3.dll` in the debug folder. but the program work without the dll. that means sqlite is linked statically.